# How to refresh the api in app if new data is added to server? retrofit 2.0

Tags: android, api, retrofit2

I have used retrofit 2.0 in my application and want to know how to refresh my page if new data is inserted in server.

Comment: please  try to add code in question

Comment: you are looking for websockets or polling

Comment: Why did you unaccept my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two common approaches to update data on client on server's data update.

The first one is pull technology (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pull_technology) 
It's implemented as periodically fetch. Eg every 5 minutes client asks server for new content. Also this approach may be implemented as long polling when server will answer only when new content is available or request will be timed out. This app

The another one is push technology (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology).
When new content is arrived to the server it sends message to client via Google FCM (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/), APNS (https://developer.apple.com/go/?id=push-notifications).